# how to remove a class from a div on page scroll at particular height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On page scroll i am trying to remove a class at particular height of a block.but while adding 30% of page scroll and removing at some height some kind of fluctuation happening

I want to make a existing div sticky on page scroll of 30% and remove sticky at default height of that block.

See below

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (docHeight - winHeight);
  console.log(scrollPercent);
  var scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent * 100);
  var footerperc = scrollPercentRounded - percentage;
  console.log(footerperc);
  st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st < lastScrollTop) {
    if (scrollPercentRounded > 30 && scrollPercentRounded < 70) {
      $('.article-page .footer-block-top').addClass('sticky').animate('slow');
    } else {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  } else {

    if (scrollPercentRounded > 30) {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').addClass('sticky');
    }

    if (scrollPercentRounded > 72) {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-block col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding ">
  <div class="footer-block-top col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="article-slide col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="arw arw-left col-xs-1 no-padding-left">


          </div>
          <div class="common-list col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 no-padding">
            <div class="list-img col-lg-4 col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs no-padding">

            </div>
            <!--event-list-title-->
            <div class="list-content col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
          <div class="common-list col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 no-padding">
            <div class="list-content col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
              Valuation</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-img col-lg-4 col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs no-padding">
            </div>
            <!--event-list-title-->
          </div>
          <div class="arw arw-right col-xs-1 no-padding-right">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cannot be sure without relevant html (*better yet a working example*) but it is common in this scenario that you need to compensate for the fact that when the element becomes sticky the page height changes (*since it is removed from the normal flow*) and consequently the scroll percentage changes.

Comment: i need footer-block-top div to be sticky at 30% of page scroll and sticky class need to be remove at default height of that block which is present just after the footer of my page,when the sticky block will reach the default block it should show the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

If you want to add **attributes** for a specific height have a look at [Mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) :)

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (docHeight - winHeight);
  console.log(scrollPercent);
  var scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent*100);
  var footerperc=scrollPercentRounded;// - percentage;
  console.log(footerperc);
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(st < lastScrollTop) {
    if (scrollPercentRounded > 30 && scrollPercentRounded < 70 ) {
      $('.article-page .footer-block-top').addClass('sticky').animate('slow');
      console.log("set sticky");
    }
    else {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }
  else {
    if (scrollPercentRounded > 30) {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').addClass('sticky');
      console.log("set sticky");
    }

    if (scrollPercentRounded > 72 ) {
      $('.article-page  .footer-block-top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-page">
  <div class="footer-block-top">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

**Short Version**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  let height = $(document).height() -$(this).height();
  let scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  let percent = Math.round( scroll / height *100 );
  
  if( percent > 30 && percent < 70 ) {
    $('.article-page').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.article-page').removeClass('sticky');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-page">
  <div class="footer-block-top">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
A
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
B
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
C
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help in responsive the sticky block getting flickering when class is getting added and removed ,can you plz check for responsive mode so the sticky block should add and remove smoothly at specific height

Comment: when the sticky block comming to 72% of page scroll i am removing sticky class at that point flactuation is happeing ,any idea how to resolve these issues

Comment: @DEBANSHUMALLICK sure, you can make a short version of your ifs: `if( percentage > 30 && percentage < 70 ) { /* sticky */ } else { /* not sticky */ }` Or is there any behaviour you want only when scrolling down? Ohterwise this will be enough.